# Conversion from Namibian Coordinates to Google Maps (WGS84)

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, convert, namibia

I have coordinates in Namibia, but don't know how to convert them to use them in Google Maps.

The system is Lo22/19°.

Then Y:  +55 435,89  X: -498 157,28

Can anyone help with a conversion?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34211/how-do-i-import-specific-coordinates-from-namibia-in-qgis? If you want to do this in JavaScript, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/pt0xfLew/

Answer (score 3):

The best tool for coordinate conversion is GDAL's cs2cs. The Lo 22/19 coordinate system is defined by EPSG code 29379, so the command line should be:

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:29379 +to +init=epsg:4326 namibia_in.txt >>namibia_out.txt
```

with this input file namibia_in.txt:

```
55435.89    -498157.28
```

Note that your coordinates are named Y;X but have to be entered in that order (and not X;Y) to give correct results. That's the oddity of West-South orientated coordinate systems. Your point is 55km west of the 19° East meridian and 498km north of the 22° South parallel.