# CRS for Namibia

Tags: coordinate-system, namibia

I would like to add coordinates to my map created on QGIS, but can not seem to find the correct CRS for Namibia.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34211/how-do-i-import-specific-coordinates-from-namibia-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110007/conversion-from-namibian-coordinates-to-google-maps-wgs84

Answer (score 4):

Try searching 'Namibia' on [epsg.io](http://epsg.io). It looks like UTM zones 33S and 34S would be good, but there might be a more appropriate CRS depending on your needs.

Comment: Or at the place where epsg.io gets its information: [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org)